# How to add userId info to Track call in Segment.Analytics.CSharp 2.3.3?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, analytics, segment

In Segment.Analytics.CSharp, the Track api doesn't have userId parameter like Analytics 3.8.1. The userId field shows null. I added Alias() and it shows an extra alias event in segment. What to do if I want Track event with userId in Segment.Analytics.CSharp?

There are two overloaded Track calls, neither of them has userId field.
function declaration:

1. public virtual void Track(string name, JsonObject properties = null)
2. public virtual void Track(string name, T properties = default(T)) where T : ISerializable

{
"anonymousId": "68ff81f6-69a7-4cb6-a7c0-6132ff6f5562",
"context": {
"library": {
"name": "Analytics-CSharp",
"version": "2.3.3"
},
"os": "Linux 4.15.0-213-generic #224-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 19 13:30:12 UTC 2023",
"platform": ".NET"
},
"event": "Navigation Menu Clicked",
"integrations": {},
"messageId": "ba249104-1afa-4502-9e46-80f120c0e88f",
"metrics": null,
"originalTimestamp": "2024-02-16T19:19:02.5168927Z",
"properties": {
"clientAppName": "Word",
"clientComponent": "desktop",
"clientName": "Next Generation Co-authoring",
"clientVersion": "1.0.510",
"customerId": "105",
"device": "Windows",
"locale": "en-us",
"navigationText": "MYFAVSND",
"productName": "Work",
"productVersion": "10.2.3880",
"userId": "100471422211588177"
},
"receivedAt": "2024-02-16T19:19:06.422Z",
"sentAt": "2024-02-16T19:19:06.032Z",
"timestamp": "2024-02-16T19:19:02.905Z",
"type": "track",
"userId": null,
"writeKey": "REDACTED"
}